# Unknown cause of crash in lambda function using Armadillo types

Tags: c++, lambda, crash, armadillo

**EDIT**: Updated code to make two functions more similar

I have a problem using armadillo types in a lambda function, which causes a crash when something tries to read an invalid memory location. If I move the same expression into a normal function everything works smoothly.

So, simple working example:

```
#define ARMA_USE_CXX11
#include <armadillo>

using namespace arma;

rowvec2 funcLambda( double value, const rowvec2 &vA, const rowvec2 &vB, const double &const1, const double &const2 ){
    return min( vA * const1, vB * const2 );
}

int main( void ){

    rowvec2 vA = {.12, .44};
    rowvec2 vB = {2, 2};
    auto const1 = double( 1.2 );
    auto const2 = 3.1;
    auto fLambda = [&]( double value ){ return min( vA * const1, vB * const2 );};
    rowvec2 z = rowvec2({0.0, 0.0});

    // This works fine
    z = funcLambda( 100, vA, vB, const1, const2 );
    // This crashes
    z = fLambda( 100 );

    return 1;
}
```

This example crashes where the note is, with and without the "using namespace arma;" line included, with and without the #define ARMA_USE_CXX11, and using 32 and 64 bit memory adressing.

I don't know if I do something wrong in the lambda function or if it is armadillo causing the problem. If I remove parts of the equation, (e.g. the multiplication of a scalar) it will work fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Henrik

Comment: I see two differences.  First, the references in the lambda are `const&`, while in the function they are `&`.  Second, `funcLambda` does construction, while `fLambda` does assignment.  If you remove these differences, does the behavior change?

Comment: @Yakk: I changed the references to const& in the function and made both function calls do assignment. Same result though. Code updated in original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Armadillo makes heavy use of lazy evaluation and has a large number of intermediate results that hold other intermediates with limited lifetime by reference<sup>1</sup>. The one that came to bite you here is the return value of `min`, and that you attempt to return it as you got it.

If you change your lambda like this:

```
auto fLambda = [&]( double value ) -> rowvec2 { return min( vA * const1, vB * const2 ); };
```

That is, if you explicitly specify that it returns a `rowvec2` instead of the `Glue<eOp<rowvector2, eop_scalar_times>, eOp<rowvector2, eop_scalar_times>, glue_min>` you get from `min`, the problem should go away because the intermediate result is converted to something tangible before the function returns.

<sup>1</sup> Yes, really. You can see this in `/usr/include/armadillo_bits/Glue_bones.hpp`. They are not meant to be stored at all.

Comment: plus 1: Ah, the "`operator auto`" / dependent reference lifetime extension problem.  (there have been some proposals to ket a rype change what value type is deduced from it for this reason -- I dub that `operator auto`)

Comment: Is there a `store` function we can use for this purpose in general?  Or is the intended storage type deducible from the expression template (so we can write one)?

Comment: @Yakk Hmm...it should be possible (and not terribly difficult) to deduce a storage type, but I don't think the facilities are there in Armadillo at the moment. I mean, the storage type of `eOp` is the storage type of its argument, the storage type of a matrix-vector multiplication is a vector -- implementing it would be some work because it'd touch every operation, but it wouldn't be rocket science.

Comment: There is also the [.eval()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#eval_member) function

Comment: @Yakk Ah, I stand corrected. The facilities are there, and the type can then be deduced with `decltype`.

Comment: @mtall: I tried using .eval(), but it did not solve my crash.